# How to set tile size in the google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to set tile size for the google map? Now every tile is 200px on my map. I found the tileSize property in MapType doc but it required creating my own MapType. I want only override tileSize with other default options.
It is possible to override only titleSize for existing map type?

My google map object:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google-map-1"), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 10,
        // tileSize: new google.maps.Size(128, 128)
      });
```

Comment: The existing map tiles are 256x256, you can't existing map tiles if you want to use a different tileSize.

Comment: So there is no possibility to display bigger resolution images on bigger screen?